# Unsubscribe link to emails in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscriber

I added a unsubscribe link in an email.  I have click on the link and it goes to the subscription center and the user can unsubscribe from the emails.  I click it and I go into SFMC and I see my user unsubscribed from SFMC but when I send a test email to co-workers it does not unsubscribe them and they are in both Service Cloud and SFMC. 
[image]

Comment: How are you sending the test?  Classic content guided send?  Or preview and test within the new content builder?  If the latter, you're referencing 1 sample record from your subscriber list or data extension and it sends to the email addresses that you specify, but in lieu of that sample record.

Comment: I attached the code above I am using for the unsubscribe.  I am sending the test from content builder and going to preview and test.  It is 1 sample record.  Could I test a test data extension with more records and different email address and test that way to have more of an idea about the records and users unsubscribing.

Comment: Code is right.  You could do what you are asking by creating some test subscribers.  But you may not need to.  The ampscript will take the sending subscriber and unsubscribe them.

Comment: on the test sends- are you referencing that the person you sent the test email to is not unsubscribed or the person that the test (via the preview) is based on is not unsub.

Comment: referring that the user is subscribed and they want to unsubscribe

Comment: I apologize but I do not know which of my two above that references.  There is the option to enter 5 email addresses in the send test section and then there is the option in preview to select a user to replicate. Which of those two is the one you are looking at status for?

Comment: I am sending an email and I am getting unsubscribed but my co-workers who have sub keys in SFMC.